# Failed to Open Stream: Permission Denied While Writing to an XML File in a WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, php, permissions, xml

I'm trying to write to an XML file in a WordPress Plugin. I'm on my local machine, a Mac running MAMP. I have PHP 5.2.13 My code is:

```
$file_handle = fopen('markers.xml', 'w');
$stringdata = "Test Info";
fwrite($file_handle, $stringdata);
fclose($file_handle);
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: fopen(markers.xml) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in
>   /Users/my_name/Sites/my_site/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin_folder/my_plugin_main_file.php
>   on line 73
>
> Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in
>   /Users/my_name/Sites/my_site/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin_folder/my_plugin_main_file.php
>   on line 75
>
> Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in
>   /Users/my_name/Sites/my_site/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin_folder/my_plugin_main_file.php
>   on line 76

markers.xml has permissions set to 777.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't set files on your server to be 777; it creates a massive security hole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check folder permissions too.

Also See this post http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#105465 - suggests he had to change to absolute from relative to get around error message.

Set of debug suggestions here:
http://www.wrensoft.com/forum/showthread.php?t=786

1) folder  permissions
2) upper/lowercase
3) abs/relative path
and finally it turned out to be an extra space somewhere,

Comment: Thank you for the help. I changed the file permissions and switched it to an absolute path.